# Error in publishing the configuration in Eclipse Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, publishing

encounter a problem " 'publishing to tomcat v7.0 server at localhost' has encountered a problem" while starting my tomcat server from eclipse. This problem arised after i tried to solve the 404 error by selecting the 'use tomcat installation' option in the setting of the server. The server seems to be running but it actually isn't.

Publishing the configuration... Error copying file to /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/catalina.policy: /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/catalina.policy (No such file or directory) /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/catalina.policy (No such file or directory) Error copying file to /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/catalina.properties: /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/catalina.properties (No such file or directory) /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/catalina.properties (No such file or directory) Error copying file to /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/context.xml: /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/context.xml (No such file or directory) /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/context.xml (No such file or directory) Error copying file to /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/server.xml: /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/server.xml (No such file or directory) /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/server.xml (No such file or directory) Error copying file to /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/tomcat-users.xml: /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/tomcat-users.xml (No such file or directory) /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/tomcat-users.xml (No such file or directory) Error copying file to /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/web.xml: /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/web.xml (No such file or directory) /usr/share/tomcat7/backup/web.xml (No such file or directory)

Comment: "no such file or directory".  Either there is 1) no such file or 2) no such directory or 3) a permissions error.  Only you can determine this; we can't check your server remotely.  Also, StackOverflow is a *programming* website; we don't allow questions concerning the configuration of a web server here.